On client nrpe linux server, what to do to set a new dh key, to solve `check_nrpe: dh key too small`
I am moving a Nagios4 server from a Debian Stretch to a Ubuntu 22.04.
I am monitoring a Debian Stretch server, when the Nagios4 server was on Debian Stretch, the check was working, now on Ubuntu 22.04 no, this is the check
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -s3 -H example.com -u -t 3 -c check_lsb_release

output:
CHECK_NRPE: (ssl_err != 5) Error - Could not complete SSL handshake with x.x.x.x: 1

/var/log/syslog:
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Certificate File: None
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Private Key File: None
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL CA Certificate File: None
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Cipher List: ALL:!MD5:@STRENGTH:@SECLEVEL=0
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Allow ADH: 1
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Log Options: 0x03
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: SSL Version: TLSv1_plus And Above
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: Connected to x.x.x.x
Jun  7 17:43:54 vps check_nrpe: Error: (!log_opts) Could not complete SSL handshake with x.x.x.x: dh key too small

I think that the problem is that the monitored server is very old, so it has a small dh key
Could not complete SSL handshake: dh key too small.
Searching on the web I found very similar cases but all referred to a Microsoft Server being monitored (with NSCLient++).
So I think that on server I am monitoring I could create a new, long enough, dh key
openssl dhparam -C 2048

but I don't now in which location on the monitored server I should put it.
I searched inside /etc/nagios/ but I can't find any configuration pointing to any dh key:

grep "pem" * -R
grep "dh" * -R
grep "key" * -R

What else I have tried:

on the monitoring server: run the check_nrpe with the --no-ssl but fails with output CHECK_NRPE: Receive header underflow - only -1 bytes received (4 expected). I believe that I should allow clear-text connections on the monitored server, but this is not an option
on the monitoring server: run the check_nrpe with the -2 flag, to force it running on an older version of the server, but it fails with syslog: check_nrpe: Error: (!log_opts) Could not complete SSL handshake with x.x.x.x: dh key too small

